# Ajax load wordpress template part

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have 2 radio buttons in a form for payment method - I want to load a template part on click via ajax.

Right now I can load only the credit card form - what i'm trying to do is if credit card is selected then load credit card template if paypal is selected then load paypal template part.

**Form Elements**

```
<input type="radio" class="radio-cc" name="method" value="creditcard"><span class="radio-span">Credit Card</span>
<input type="radio" class="radio-paypal" name="method" value="paypal"><span class="radio-span">Paypal</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input[name=method]").change(function(){ 
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'GET',  
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',  
        data: {  
            action: 'CCAjax'     
        },  
        success: function(textStatus){  
           $( '.default-form' ).append( textStatus ); 
        },  
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
            alert(errorThrown);  
        }  
    });  
});
```

**PHP**

```
function CCAjax()
    {
       get_template_part('cc');
        die();
    }

    // creating Ajax call for WordPress  
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_CCAjax', 'CCAjax');
    add_action('wp_ajax_CCAjax', 'CCAjax');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to pass the Value of the chosen method:

**jQuery**

```
$("input[name=method]").change(function(){
  var chosenmethod = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',  
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',  
    data: { action : 'CCAjax', chosen : chosenmethod },  
    success: function(textStatus){  
       $( '.default-form' ).html( textStatus ); 
    },  
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
        alert(errorThrown);  
    }  
  });  
});
```

**PHP**

```
function CCAjax()
{
   if($_POST['chosen']=='creditcard'){
     get_template_part('cc');
   } else {
     get_template_part('paypal');
   }
   exit();
}

// creating Ajax call for WordPress  
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_CCAjax', 'CCAjax');
add_action('wp_ajax_CCAjax', 'CCAjax');
```

Comment: thanks man - it's only loading the cc part even i click on paypal. Also if I click on CC the change to Paypal it Loads both etc.....is there any way to clear the one not used as well?

Comment: ok i figured out why only one is showing and edited your answer. - any ideas to clear the form not in use if the other one is selected? Thanks!

Comment: Try .html(textStatus); instead of .append(textStatus); in the jquery-ajax success.